# Not able to transfer large files from DVD to windows 7 desktop

Tags: windows-7, dvd, file-transfer

So I have a lot of large files (some .rar and some .iso) mostly over 7 GB on those dual layer 8.7 GB disks. Yesterday I wanted to copy those files from the DVD to a 1TB NTFS format hard disk. But it shows I/O error after 3.7 GBs. This is happening for multiple disks (which ever have individual files that are over 5 GB). I tried transferring those files to the internal Hard Disk, but that too is not really working. I don't know if the disks are faulty or my DVD Drive. But since my DVD Drive can successfully transfer files below 5 GB, I doubt that is the problem.

I am on Windos 7 Home basic but also tried it with Fedora, no dice.

Comment: what file system?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the harddisk is NTFS, I don't know about the disk themselves.

Comment: We can rule out the old fat32 / 4gb issue then

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, we can. that was the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: What's the I/O error you get?

Comment: Can you copy with "COPY" in a CMD.EXE window?

Answer (score 0):

your dvd-drive is either not capable of reading THESE discs .. OR the dvds got so bad that now your dvd-drive is not capable of reading THESE discs.

find a different dvd-drive.

Comment: I am sure the disks are fine because these are fresh copies. How can I be really sure that my drive cannot read these large disks? Because it can read it, if there are individual files.

Comment: so, you checked if every bit you put onto that (unreliable) medium is exactly the same as on the original files?

Comment: I am fairly certain, yes because they were taken from an old HDD and then burned and given to me.

Comment: @rick_2047 - Are you 100% certain have you compared the Checksums for the files?  Have you tried a different DVD drive, does your optical drive, even support reading DVD+DL disks?

Comment: so, you checked if every bit you put onto that (unreliable) medium is exactly the same as on the original files? look, you can not say "yes, i am certain" and on the other hand claim "i can not read the files" and think everything is ok.

Comment: @akira okey, I would just get access to a new drive tomorrow and check out if the disks work there.